# I want to change language in a select list and whole site changes to selected language(All content)

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I want to have four languages Catalan, Spanish , French and English. English language will be default.If i change language to be spanish,i want the whole site to change to spanish or if i change to french the whole site should changed to french.

[Example site](http://www.basel.com/en). I want to know how this would have been done ?

Any help really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need Internationalization module, core's Locale module will already do the job. It makes content translatable, so yes you need to translate it manually. When you enable Locale and edit a node, the option to enter a translation will appear.

Comment: So i need to manually enter each content for each language. A node in english, correspondingly i need to create three more nodes for same content for other languages. Is that what you meant manually ?

Answer (score 0):

if i where you i would use google translate for websites its very easy ......go to google webmaster tools choose  google translate for site take add your site domain and generate the code ...then take the first code and put it in the page.tpl.php in the header section 
and take the second code and put it after the  directly and at then you should have 52 language on your site all the site is translated to your selected language and you could limit it to any no of languges from the webmaster tool before generate the code  and inject it to your page.tpl.php

Comment: google translate doesn't do the translation properly.